# Create a mask from labels to compute loss with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having troubles creating a mask without using a for loop.
I've got a numpy array of size `N` with my labels and I want to create a mask of size `NxN` where `mask[i, j] = True` if and only if `y[i] == y[j]`.
I've managed to do so by using a for loop :

```
mask = np.asarray([np.where(y==y[k], 1, 0) for k in range(len(y))])
```

But I'm working on a GPU and this greatly increase the compute time. How can I  do it without looping?

Comment: If an answer helped you, please accept it. Otherwise, please explain what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
n = 3
a = np.arange(n)

np.equal.outer(a, a)

# this is the same as
a[:,None] == a
```

Output:

```
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]])
```

This is basically comparing the elements from a cartesian product. `a[0] == a[1], a[1] == a[1], a[1] == a[2]` and so forth, which is why the diagonal values are `True` when using `np.arange`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.repeat` and `.T`

`a` and `b` are just arbitrary data - the labels in your case.

```
import numpy as np

size = 4

a = np.arange(size)[:, None]
b = a.T
b[0, 2] = 1

c = np.repeat(a.T, repeats=size, axis=0)
d = np.repeat(b, repeats=size, axis=0).T

print(c)
print(d)

e = np.equal(c, d)

print(e)
```

out:

```
[[0 1 1 3]
 [0 1 1 3]
 [0 1 1 3]
 [0 1 1 3]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [3 3 3 3]]
[[ True False False False]
 [False  True  True False]
 [False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For problems like these, np.indices is your friend:

```
dims = (len(y), len(y))
inds = np.indices(dims)
mask = np.empty(dims, dtype=bool)
mask[inds] = y[inds[0]] == y[inds[1]]
```

edit:
Kevin's more specific solution is more concise and almost certainly faster than this method.